# Fetch data from database while comparing id with a column[type=jsonnb] having json data in Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column called `vendor` having jsonnb type and a json data like `[{"id":"1","name":"Dev"}]`

I wanted to select row data puting this column in where clause like `WHERE vendor.id=1`

So how can i do that, any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [contains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) operator `@>`:

```
select *
from the_table
where vendor @> '[{"id":"1"}]'::jsonb;
```

Comment: it's not working it says id is not define @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @CodeBreaker: my query does not reference a column named `id` so that it can't cause that error

Comment: Ok thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for the reply.  I will check it... it will works definatly.

Comment: My first solution using `->>` wasn't correct though. I didn't see that it's an array

Comment: Yeah.. that what i wanted to say... Now, this is working... thanks.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name when i put in $sql="select *
from the_table
where vendor @> '[{"id":"1"}]'::jsonb". it giver error because of " " what can i do?